# Can a US company give equity to an Indian?

Tags: united-states, india, equity

Is it possible for a US company to give some percentage of its ownership to an Indian?

**Background:** I'm an Indian citizen working with a US client. I'm located in India. Together we are developing a product for the US market. As per the verbal agreement, my client has promised to give 10-30% of ownership of the US company. So is this possible? Note that I'll not be investing money, rather my contribution comes in the product development.

And Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "rather my contribution comes in the product development."  That's called *sweat equity*.  What kind of visa do you have?

Comment: Right now, I don't have any Visa.

Comment: Presumably that means you're in India?

Comment: yes, I'm in India.

Comment: "Per the verbal agreement" is the same as saying "this will never happen". Get it in writing, as soon as possible!

Comment: This triggers some warnings about a posible scam: you have no contract (no, "verbal agreement" does not count) and in the event of something going wrong with the deal you will have to pay some lawyer in the USA to fight for you (in the case that there is something for the lawyer to fight with), with you probably being unable to even get into the country... And you probably cannot even know if the other guy is getting rich out of the product so you will have to trust his word. Get a proper contract NOW!

Comment: Thank you @Grade'Eh'Bacon and SJuan76. I understand your concerns. Right now my US partner is doing market research and I'm involved in product development. Surely I'll have the written agreement before the product is ready.

Comment: @Vivek You want a written agreement before you do any work for them! There is a very high chance that things will work out poorly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for a US company to give some percentage of its ownership to an Indian?

Yes, with some restrictions.

https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=545805cd-814e-433c-b141-09bba35a1247

> Subject to certain industry-specific restrictions and state law exceptions (eg, certain restrictions sometimes seen with respect to foreign investments in agricultural real property) federal and state law generally do not restrict foreign ownership of, or investment in, US companies. However, **such acquisitions may be subject to review by the Committee on Foreign Investment in the United States (CFIUS)**. If CFIUS determines that a transaction raises national security concerns, it can impose a range of mitigation measures on the parties (which may include requiring the certain information regarding sensitive US government activities to be shielded from the non-US investor, or even unwinding the transaction if concerns cannot be addresses through other measures).
>
> In addition, the Commerce Department’s Bureau of Economic Affairs **may require US companies to submit a report** (the Survey of New Foreign Direct Investment in the United States (Form BE-13)) **if a foreign person acquires 10% or more of the voting securities of the US company.**

Lawyers must get involved.  You'll need a US lawyer, probably will need to visit, etc